# windows 8.1 preview to pro version all programs deleted

Tags: windows-8.1, partition-recovery, windows-8.1-preview, testdisk

After the update from Windows 8.1 to Windows 8.1 pro all programs were deleted.

At the update dialog they said that you have to reinstall all apps. I understood this to mean only the apps in the store.

Unfortunately windows have not created a recovery point.

Is it possible to go back to windows 8.1 preview by recovering the old partition table?

Comment: - This was to be expected.  Even if a recovery point was created it wouldn't have helped.  Your migration was one-way there isn't a way to go back.

Comment: @Ramhound even if I restore the old partition table?

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a partition table is.  It was well publicized that the preview did not have an upgrade path that preserves your installed applications.  It is a one-way update, just reinstall your applications and pay closer attention to the fine print next time.

Comment: The partition table won't save anything. The old partition isn't there now, and you are stuck like this. Recovery is not possible.

Comment: The partition didn't change at all.  A partition is an area of the disk.  The update changed files within that area, not the extent of the area itself.  "Partition table" is the wrong idea to be thinking with for this update.

Comment: @TaXXoR - Your data was overwritten. For recovery to be possible data cannot be overwritten, even if you were to recovery the data, the software would still need to be reinstalled because the registry hive was wiped.  I am going to have to flag this as a duplicate because of the type of answers you will get, while I am going to upvote Simon's answer for being accurate, I just don't feel a few sentences does this subject justice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the migration to Windows 8.1 was permanent. You cannot go back to the old preview or anything, the data was removed after you upgraded. You will have to reinstall all your applications. The partition table has nothing to do with your apps, as the partition the preview was on will have been erased and replaced with the new 8.1 data.